# Implement a specific class from other module

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, dependency-management

I have a project with some modules. I have a module that uses only a class from other module and I don't want to make a dependency of the entire module. How do I depend of this exact class?

Right now is like this:

```
implementation project(':module')
```

Comment: Gradle doesn't allow you to express a dependency on a class, at least not in the sense that you are describing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guessed that but maybe there was possibility... Looks like not!